# System.OutOfMemoryException как исправить?

Tags: c#, selenium

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой `SystemOutOfMemoryException`.
код для скриншотов

```
public Bitmap TakeScreenshot(By by)
{
    // 1. Make screenshot of all screen
    var screenshotDriver = Browser as ITakesScreenshot;
    Screenshot screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
    var bmpScreen = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray));
    
    // 2. Get screenshot of specific element
    IWebElement element = Browser.FindElement(by);
    var cropArea = new Rectangle(element.Location, element.Size);
    return bmpScreen.Clone(cropArea, bmpScreen.PixelFormat);
}
```

Comment: Что можно понять из вашего вопроса?

Comment: проверьте element.Location, думаю что у него негативные координаты X и Y.

Comment: Нужно больше информации.

Comment: Bitmap.Clone бросает OOM если параметр rect находится за пределами изображения-источника. Проверяйте размеры.